# get first day of given week

Tags: c

I have the current week as an integer (43 as of now).
I need the date for Monday in a format like 'Mon Oct 25'.

Thought I could accomplish that by a function from  but I don't know how to do that.
Any suggestions?

EDIT:
I tried the suggestion from R., but it doesn't give the expected result. Did I implement it wrong?

```
time_t monday;
char date_format[32];
time_t now = time(NULL);
struct tm *tm = localtime(&now);

tm->tm_yday = 0; // reset to Jan 1st
tm->tm_hour = 24 * 7 * WEEK + 24; // goto Sun and add 24h for Mon

monday = mktime(tm);

strftime(date_format, 31, "%a : %D", tm);

printf("%s\n", date_format);
```

Comment: Good luck. ISO-8601 defines what a "week number" means (i.e., how to work out what the date is of day 1 week 1, depending what day of the week the year starts on). Specifically, Week 1 is whichever week contains the first Thursday of the year. But not everyone uses that definition consistently. So before you can write any code, you have to know what the input actually means.

Comment: The available solutions depend on your environment.

Comment: Remember, too, that this answer will change depending on what year it is.

Comment: My answer, below, took the year into account.

Comment: @Steve, my definition of week number is 'date +%U' :)

Comment: @ClosedID: then it's non-ISO. %U uses Sunday as the first day of the week (so week 1 is, I think, the week containing the first Wednesday). %V is the ISO version, using Monday.

Comment: @ClosedID: `mktime` ignores `tm_yday` in the input. You need to reset the `tm_mon` and `tm_mday` fields. The bad date you got looks like about 43 weeks from now. But the code is still wrong: the first day of week 43 *is not* necessarily 43*7 days after the first day of the year. The first day of the year could be in either week 0 or week 1, depending what day of the week it is, and the first day of week 43 is always a Sunday (in your definition), so isn't so simply related to the first day of the year...

Comment: ...  As R. says, you need to work out which day Week 1 Day 1 actually is. Once you have your definition of week number, there are seven possibilities, depending what day of the week Jan 1st is (and some of those possibilities are in the previous year). Once you have Week 1 Day 1, then you can add `(43-1)*7*24` hours to get Week 43 Day 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: Not tested, but given the current year, this should do it:

```
const char *months[12]={"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep",
                        "Oct","Nov","dec","Jan"};
/* Start with January 1st of the current year */
struct tm curYear={
  0, // secs
  0, // mins
  0, // hours
  1, // Day of month
  0, // Month (Jan)
  year,
  0, // wday
  0, // yday
  0}; // isdst

/* Offset the number of weeks specified */
time_t secsSinceEpoch=mktime(&curYear)+
                      weekNum*86400*7; /* Shift by number of weeks */
struct tm *candidateDate=gmtime(&secsSinceEpoch);

/* If the candidate date is not a Monday, shift it so that it is */
if (candidateDate->tm_wday!=1)
{
  secsSinceEpoch+=(86400*(candidateDate->tm_wday-1)); 
  candidateDate=gmtime(&secsSinceEpoch);
}

printf("Mon %s %d",months[candidateDate->tm_mon],candidateDate->tm_mday\n");
```

You may have to adjust the formulas in this code depending on what exactly you mean by week 43 of a given year or to conform with ISO-8601, for example. However, this should present you with good boiler plate code to get started. You may also want to parameterize the day of the week, so that it is not hard coded.

Also, if you want, you can avoid the months array and having to format the time, by truncating the result of the `ctime` function, which just so happens to display more than you asked for. You would pass to it a pointer to the `secsSinceEpoch` value and truncate its output to just display the day of the week, the day of the month and the abbreviation of the months name.

Comment: You're making it too difficult. See my answer.

Comment: you're really good at writing code without testing it :) I only needed to change the array length to 13 and decrement the weeknumber by one. Then I get 'Mon Oct 25' which is absolutely correct.

Comment: Thanks for the complement. For what it's worth, I did go over the code mentally some five times trying to make sure that no bugs snuck in. But, ultimately, the only way to ensure that any piece of code works is to test it.

Answer (score 2):

The `mktime` function can do this. Simply initialize `struct tm foo` to represent the first day of the year (or first day of the first week of the year, as needed), then set `tm_hour` to `24*7*weeknum` and call `mktime`. It will normalize the date for you.

Comment: Is this behavior compiler specific or part of the C standard?

Comment: @Michael: the standard says that the initial values can be out of range, and that they are "forced" into range. It doesn't say how they're forced (at least, not in 7.23.2.3/2 of C99), so possibly you could argue the standard doesn't require it, but I think the intention is that time overflow calculations are done. @R. Do you have to set the time to (e.g.) midday on the first day, rather than midnight, to avoid being out by one day due to daylight savings?

Comment: That's a nifty solution but I can't get it to work as expected. I added the suggested code to my original post. It prints 'Sun : 08/28/11' for current week 43. Someone sees the error?

Comment: You implemented it wrong. Don't call `localtime` then set `tm_yday` - this won't work since `tm_yday` is a derived value that can't override others. Instead make the whole `struct tm` from scratch, or else call `localtime` then zero out all the time/day elements (just leaving the year) before doing the procedure in my answer.