# Week number to month

Tags: objective-c, date

Given that I have the week number of a  particular year, how do I get the month's name in which the week starts? (using Obj-c)

e.g. Week 2 of 2009 should convert to January 2009
and Week 51 of 2004 should convert to December 2004

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer at question: [get first day of given week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059853/get-first-day-of-given-week)

```
//convert week to month
    int weekNum = sdi.mWeek;
    const char *months[13]={"January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December","January"};
    struct tm curYear={0,0,0,1,0,sdi.mYear,0,0,0}; 
    time_t secsSinceEpoch=mktime(&curYear)+weekNum*86400*7;
    struct tm *candidateDate=gmtime(&secsSinceEpoch);    
    if (candidateDate->tm_wday!=1)
    {
        secsSinceEpoch+=(86400*(candidateDate->tm_wday-1)); 
        candidateDate=gmtime(&secsSinceEpoch);
    }    
    // [months[candidateDate->tm_mon]] returns month
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use a date library to do so, but if wanna calculate it, here is a explained solution

you need to know if it's a leap year. each month has 4 weeks plus a few days depending on the month.

for example:

january is 4 weeks plus 3 days
...
april is 4 weeks plus 2 days

store the days extra for each month (the only one that may vary is february that may have 28 or 29 days, depending on if it's a leap year or not)

```
$extra_days = (january => 3, march => 3, april => 2, december => 3);
```

calculate february extra days (0 or 1), you'll have to calculate if it's a leap year...you can do this using an operation such as ->

```
$your_year mod 4
```

something like :

```
if (($your_year - REFERENCE_LEAP_YEAR) mod 4 == 0) then "it's a leap year"
```

now you got the extra days for each month you can calculate the month. Each month has 4 weeks but you need a counter to know if the extra days fulfill a week. For example:

```
january = 3 extra days
-> weeks = 4 - extra_days = 3 febraury = 1 extra day
-> weeks = 8 - extra_days = 4 march = 3 extra days
-> weeks 12 - extra_days = 7
***now you have an extra week so..
-> weeks 13 - extra_days
```

...