# Convert week number for a certain year to a month name

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring, nsdate

After searching through SO but apart from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995344/week-number-to-month) I found no solutions. I'm thinking about creating a method that would accept the `int` of the week number and the `int` of the year and that would return an `NSString` with the name of the month:

`- (NSString *)getMonthNameFromNumber:(int)weekNumber andYear:(int)year`

But I can't find a way to approach this problem. Would be glad if anyone could help with advices.

Comment: NSDateComponents could be useful.

Comment: Use NSDateFormatter `monthSymbols` instead of `setDateFormat`. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDateFormatter/monthSymbols

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this will do

```
- (NSString *)monthNameForWeek:(NSUInteger)week inYear:(NSInteger)year {
    NSDateComponents * dateComponents = [NSDateComponents new];
    dateComponents.year = year;
    dateComponents.weekOfYear = week;
    dateComponents.weekday = 1; // 1 indicates the first day of the week, which depends on the calendar
    NSDate * date = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM"];
    return [formatter stringFromDate:date];
}
```

Note that this is dependent on the current calendar set in the device preferences.

In case this doesn't fit your needs, you can provide a `NSCalendar` instance and use it to retrieve the date instead of using `currentCalendar`. By doing so you can configure things like which is the first day of the week and so on. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html) of `NSCalendar` is worth a read.

If using a custom calendar is a common case, just change the implementation to something like

```
- (NSString *)monthNameForWeek:(NSUInteger)week inYear:(NSInteger)year {
     [self monthNameForWeek:week inYear:year calendar:[NSCalendar currentCalendar]];
}

- (NSString *)monthNameForWeek:(NSUInteger)week inYear:(NSInteger)year calendar:(NSCalendar *)calendar {
    NSDateComponents * dateComponents = [NSDateComponents new];
    dateComponents.year = year;
    dateComponents.weekOfYear = week;
    dateComponents.weekday = 1; // 1 indicates the first day of the week, which depends on the calendar
    NSDate * date = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM"];
    return [formatter stringFromDate:date];
}
```

---

<sup>As an unrelated side note, you should avoid `get` for methods names, unless you are returning a value indirectly.</sup>

Comment: ... which should return the name of the month in which the first day of the week falls. You could use another date components to advance 6 days and check the last day of the week if you were concerned about weeks that straddle months. Also be prepared for slightly different answers in different regions — Monday is the start of the week in most of the world but in the US it's Sunday. I'd expect Apple to have factored that in when you talk about when week N starts.

Comment: @Tommy you can configure a `NSCalendar` instance. Added a note.

Comment: `year` and `weekOfYear` are not sufficient to create a valid date (it will default to the 1st Jan of the specified year). See my answer for the use of `weekday`.

Answer (score 2):

With anything to do with dates, you need to involve a calendar. Your question assumes the Gregorian Calendar, but I suggest you change your method declaration to:

```
- (NSString*)monthNameFromWeek:(NSInteger)week year:(NSInteger)year calendar:(NSCalendar*)cal;
```

From this, there is also the ambiguity of which day we're talking about. For example (this hasn't been checked), week 4 of 2015 may contain both January and February. Which one is correct? For this example, we'll use a weekday of 1, which indicates Sunday (in the UK Gregorian Calendar), and we'll use whatever month this falls in to.

As such, your code would be:

```
// Set up our date components
NSDateComponents* comp = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
comp.year = year;
comp.weekOfYear = week;
comp.weekday = 1;

// Construct a date from components made, using the calendar
NSDate* date = [cal dateFromComponents:comp];

// Create the month string
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM"];
return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```